# How to do a case insensitive first_or_create?

Tags: ruby, datamapper

Based on the datamapper documentation, the proper way to do this is

```
thing = Thing.first_or_create({ 
  conditions: ['lower(value) = ?', some_value.downcase]
}, { 
  value: some_value.downcase
})
```

Given that `Thing.first(conditions: ['lower(value) = ?', some_value.downcase])` correctly returns the first record, and `first_or_create` accepts two parameters if the query differs from the initial values.

However, the above throws

```
The attribute 'conditions' is not accessible in Thing
```

The code I'm currently using simply does the `first` and `create` separately.

```
thing = Thing.first(conditions: ['lower(value) = ?', some_value.downcase])
thing = Thing.create(value: some_value.downcase) if email.nil?
```

But I feel there must be a more correct way, given the existence of `first_or_create`.

Comment: someone should answer this :(